# Nightly overwhelming sewer gas smell from shower drain only while in use

Tags: plumbing, shower, gas, sewer, p-trap

Ok here is a doozy we have been dealing with for over a year.

House was a new build 2012 and we had never had any plumbing issues until we had our roof replaced a bit over a year back and around the same time began to experience occasional sewer gas smell from the shower floor drain and also across the house from the washing machine, but only while actively in use draining water. Over time it has progressively become more consistent (it is now daily) and stronger odor. I used a flammable/sewer gas detector and it registered up to 50ppm after the shower ran for approximately 5 minutes, then when shut off returned to zero. In the laundry room the gas odor stays in the washer tub until the room gets sufficiently aired out.

Based on the coincidental roof replacement, I assumed the "upgraded" wrapover roof vent boots somehow were constricting the vents and so we had them all replaced with standard 3 in 1s with new extended PVC. This did nothing to address the issue. Plumbers also ran cameras down the vents to check for obstructions and everything is clear and clean. I used my endoscope and verified both the shower and washing machine traps are holding water and not dry.

We then ran cameras from the rearmost cleanout adjacent to the master bath all the way to the sewer tie and and found no leaks, clogs, or issues. Similarly we checked the front yard main cleanouts both into the house and away towards the sewer and found it to be in nearly new condition with no leaks or clogs. As a test, I uncapped the main cleanouts in the front yard and ran the shower, and still got sewer gas smell coming from the drain (this is what is most confusing). What is also unusual is that if we leave the house for a vacation and return after no plumbing has been used for approximately a week, we do not get any sewer gas for 2 to 3 days before it completely returns.

We next called and had the city perform a sewer pull and degrease/washout which also had no effect.

As of today we can hardly stand taking showers, especially at night. The entire master bath and bedroom is overcome with sewer gas on a daily basis. The washer tub gas is less consistent - some days we can run the washer with no issues and other days it too becomes overwhelming.

Not sure what to do now - none of our other drains have any issues including half bath, 2nd bath with kids shower, kitchen sink, etc. I cant make much sense of what could cause sewer gas to pressure past the shower trap while it is actively draining instead of simply exiting though the roof vent like it presumably had been doing for over the past decade. I even tried installing a backflow preventer in the shower drain but as soon as there is flow through it and into the trap, the gas is seemingly bubbling past and into the shower.

Currently at wits end, my plumber essentially gave up on us. No idea what to check next. Help!

Comment: sounds like your p-traps are siphoning....   you could have the wrong slope or could be over the critical arm length.  you could have also had a sewer backup event and the p-traps are now coated in sewer sludge which when you add water activates the smell post vacation.  how large is your p-trap pipe (1.5" pipe, 2")?, how far to the vent(s)?  how air sealed is your house, are you highly negatively pressurized / do you have a 600cfm range hood?

Comment: If it was not there before but it is now happening, it might be just blocked roof vents.

Comment: Wondering if the roof work loosen up some vent joints.  They would only leak air/smells so be harder to see.

Comment: I'm with @FreshCodemonger, sounds like a siphon due to bad or non-existing vent

Comment: As far as blocked/compromised vents go, that's something that was specifically checked with cameras to ensure they were all intact after we re-replaced the boot jacks and extended the piping further above the roof. They are all perfect.

With regards to an improper slope/arm length for the traps and proximity to vents, we had not had any issues with the setup for the past 11 years so unsure why it would begin out of the blue. Inspecting the entire drain system via cleanouts and the traps with my endoscope showed them to be in like-new condition with no sludge, cracks, or leaks.

Comment: I also thought about negative pressure situations, but we haven't changed any of our exhaust vents in the house since build, and we are not getting any siphoning and gas effect from all but just the master shower and laundry drains. I also noticed no changes if we run the shower with the bathroom window open. If the house was truly at negative pressure I presume it would affect all the other traps as well.

Comment: It might not be the shower.   Sewer smells are hard to localize...they waft far.   Maybe there is another drain nearby where the trap has dried out letting sewer gases rise.  If you run a fan during a shower, as air is pushed out the vent, other air is drawn into the bathroom.

Comment: We have determined it is the shower drain with certainty, as its an immense odor thats very localized within the shower stall after ~5 min of water running. It dissipates once the water is shut off, and this was verified with the gas detector. I also closed the stoppers on the separate master bathroom tub and vanity drains during the shower to be sure.

Comment: @ChrisFoskey Closed the stoppers and plugged the vents too on tub and vanity? A lump of Mortite or modeling clay can serve as a temporary plug.

Comment: @MTA yes basically sealed off the tub and sinks. The gas is definitely pushing past the trap while there is flow though it from draining the shower in use. When static, the trap water seals properly.

I cant understand why the gas would be pushing past a flowing trap instead of using the path of least resistance up through the roof vent, which my plumber checked and said is clear.

Comment: @ChrisFoskey Did the start of the odor coincide with installing a fancy new high-flow shower head? The clothes washer also causes the problem, and washers have relatively high flow when emptying. Is there a way to adjust your water flow in the shower to be barely adequate? If you can't adjust flow, could you temporarily install a low-flow shower head? Borrow one from the kids' shower? If none of these are possible, stand on a vinyl place mat (or something) that blocks 90% of the drain while showering and see what happens. Lack of an odor when drain flow is reduced could be an important clue.

Comment: @MTA No changes to shower head flow. A couple weeks ago I even tried installing a backflow preventer (2" drain) to see if it would have an effect. The drain empties slightly slower as the water has to push past the diaphragm before going into the trap, but amazingly ANY flow though allows gas to enter the shower past it and the problem remains. At times the backflow device totally stops the flow momentarily and standing water appears, and there is no gas until it starts to drain again. There have been no changes to the washer either, and we never had any issues with it for the past 10 years.

Comment: @ChrisFoskey That's a clue: "At times the backflow device totally stops the flow momentarily and standing water appears" can only be true if the air pressure in your drain line beyond the backflow preventer is greater than air pressure in the room *plus* the standing head of water in the shower drain. That should never happen. Air pressure in all your drains beyond P-traps should be equal to outdoor air pressure. You can measure pressure difference room vs drain vs outdoors with a U-tube manometer and long tubing or find a more technically oriented plumber who can figure this out on site.

Comment: @MTA good point, though the backflow preventer only held water to the point it stagnated one time, and it was after I had installed it closer to the top of the drain exit as an experiment. Could it have been that larger "column" of air between the backflow valve and the drain side of the p-trap water "U" that stopped the flow? Also, I am looking into doing a smoke test just to check the box of no hidden system leaks.

Comment: Does the master bath have a tub/shower or just a shower? Where did you place this backflower preventer? Is the plumbing under a slab or is it accessible? What kind of foundation? Can you get into the attic and see if the vents that should go through the roof are as they should be? Is the master bath vent combined with the washing machine vent into a single vent penetrating the roof?

Answer (score 1):

You’ve observed that sewer gas enters when water flows down the master bath shower drain or the laundry drain. It would make sense if debris had fallen down the stack vent and obstructs the venting for of these drains. More complex explanations are also possible, like there were two roof vents before and only one now because the roofers only brought one vent cuff so they roofed over the other vent.

All explanations depend on the plumber only scoping the stack itself and not actually scoping each vent line to confirm the shower vent and laundry vent are clear. If those vent lines were actually open then those traps would not be siphoning out and allowing gas to enter one glug at a time.

The building air pressure would result in continuous sewer gas intrusion. It would not be limited to when the laundry or shower was in use.

There’s sure to be a better plumber who can scope the lines, and auger out the debris. Finding that better plumber is your best bet.

Failing that, your odds of directing a scope and cleaning the debris out yourself by directing either an auger or a high pressure water jet into the correct vent branch are low. A number of schemes involving large shop vacs on the stack vent and blowing air into the shower drain to dislodge and remove the debris come to mind, but I’m skeptical any of them will work on heavy roofing debris.